# Android - Can I register the broadcast with LocalBroadcastManger in Application.onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

So within my app, sometimes I need to send a broadcast multiple times based on the service response. So I cannot register it in a specific activity since the activity needs to be visible when we send it (correct me if I'm wrong).

So is it possible I could register it in `Application.onCreate()` and send the broadcast any time I want? I have problem receive the broadcast now, never received once, does the `context` used here should be the same?

Should I just switch to a global broadcast receiver instead of the `LocalBroadcastManager`? But I really don't want this to be global across all apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit all of your activities from abstract class BroadcastReceiverActivity in which you should register BroadcastReceiver in `onResume` and unregister in `onPause` callbacks.